# reg expression for 2 alpha,2 numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

reuirement: At least 2  Alpha  ,2 numbers with minimum 8 characters
alpha numeric can be anywhere
Minimum length of 8 characters (maximum length of 32 characters
Must contain at least 2 alpha and 2 numeric characters
Can include Dash, Comma, Period, Space( )

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{2})(?=(.*\d){2})(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[A-Za-z]*$)
```

i tried the above but its validating  only two consequtive characters
for example test case1 :  te3f3.,-    (passed)
            test case2    :t2g2.,-g   (failed)but this have to pass even though alha characters are not consecutive

Answer (score 3):

To find if a string contains 2 of something, you have to allow for there to be characters between. Surround the look-ahead expressions in non-capturing groups.

```regex
^(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=(?:.*\d){2})[A-Za-z0-9 ,.-]{8,32}$
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF4zG9/3)

For a faster regex, be more specific than `.*`:

```regex
^(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=(?:\D*\d){2})[A-Za-z0-9 ,.-]{8,32}$
```